# Get the index (counter) of an 'ng-repeat' item with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, counter

I am using AngularJS and its `ng-repeat` directive to display a sequence of questions. I need to number each question starting with `1`. How do I display and increment such a counter with `ng-repeat`? Here is what I have so far:

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: {questionTypesId: questionType, selected: true}">
        <div>
            <span class="name">
                {{ question.questionText }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
                <span class="name">
                    {{answer.selector}}. {{ answer.answerText }}
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Angularjs documentation is full of examples, you just need to take some time and explore it.

See this example here : [ngRepeat example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#example) , it's the same case.

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: {questionTypesId: questionType, selected: true}">
        <div>
            <span class="name">
                {{$index + 1}} {{ question.questionText }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
                <span class="name">
                    {{answer.selector}}. {{ answer.answerText }}
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so what is the answer? :D

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, i just comment it here: Using `ngIf` at the same time will still increment `$index`, which wouldn't work in your example. Like i want to use something like `ng-class="{ 'even': $index % 2 == 0 }"` Trying to find a workaround for this without touching the controller, if anyone knows how would love to hear it.

Comment: i'm sorry, i can't find out the problem you are trying to explain, can you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 37):

Reached here by searching for something similar.

Here is what worked for me.

```
{{$index + 1}}
```

+1  is added because the index starts from 0.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to get an index for the given array in ng-repeat

### Using $index

```
<th ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(3 + 1) track by $index">{{$index}}</th>
```

### Using a counter

This method is useful when you have nested ng-repeat and you need counters for both loops...the following example uses counter row. Although track by $index is required, it is not used for the logic.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(row, y) in getNumber(h.seats.length, 3) track by $index">
                    <td>{{row+1}}</td>
```

In both cases counter starts with 0 and you can offset using +1 if you like

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If we want to count down, like 5 -> 4 -> 3 etc. How we will achieve this? Thanks

Comment: If we want to count down you can do like this: <tr ng-repeat="(row, y) in getNumber(h.seats.length, 3) | filter: seats as r">
                    <td>{{ r.length - $index }}</td>