# How to get the key value or iteration of a certain item in angular ui tree?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I have a piece of code which is a basic example of how to use angular-ui-tree:

```
<div ui-tree>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list" ui-tree-node>
      <div ui-tree-handle>
        {{item.title}}
      </div>
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.items">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.items" ui-tree-node>
          <div ui-tree-handle>
            {{subItem.title}}
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Now if I have an {{item}}, is there a way to get the item's iteration on the loop? Like for example I want to get a condition that if this item's current loop iteration is an odd number or an even number for instance, I could change the style of the certain node of the tree like say I have an alternate blue and red items based on its iteration if it's odd or even.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335095/angularjs-ng-repeat-counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **$index** in your **ng-repeat** loop it will give you the interation number-

```
ng-class="{ even : $index%2 == 0, odd : $index%2 != 0 }"
```

**CSS**

```
.even {
    color: blue;
}
.odd {
    color: red;
}
```

**Final code**

```
   <div ui-tree>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="list">
            <li ng-repeat="item in list" ui-tree-node>
                <div ui-tree-handle>
                    {{item.title}}
                </div>
                <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.items">
                    <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.items" ui-tree-node>
                        <div ui-tree-handle ng-class="{ even : $index%2 == 0, odd : $index%2 != 0 }">
                            {{subItem.title}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great happy to help.